# Paging Class DLL - Don't Repeat Yourself

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, dll, dry

I have a simple paging system. I use it everywhere with minor changes. I want to make a class or dll file and use it more generally. I do not want to repeat myself.

MY CONTROLLER:

```
public ActionResult Index(int sayfa = 1)
{
    int totalPage = Posts.Count();
    int postPerPage = 10;
    int pageCount = totalPage / postPerPage;
    if ((totalPage % postPerPage) > 0)
    {
        pageCount++;
    }
    ViewBag.PageCurrent = sayfa;
    ViewBag.PageCount = pageCount;
    Posts = (IOrderedQueryable<Post>)Posts.Skip(postPerPage * (sayfa - 1)).Take(postPerPage);
    return View(Posts.ToList());
}
```

MY VIEW:

```
<div class="pagination">
    @{
        int pageCurrent = ViewBag.PageCurrent;
        int pageCount = ViewBag.PageCount;

        if (pageCurrent != 1)
        {
            @Html.ActionLink(" ", "Index", "Post", new { sayfa = pageCurrent - 1 }, new { @class = "previous" })
        }

        for (int i = 1; i <= pageCount; i++)
        {
            if (i == pageCurrent)
            {            
                <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Post", new { sayfa = i, })" style="background-color: #af3425">@i</a>
            }
            else
            {
                <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Post", new { sayfa = i } )">@i</a>
            }     
        }

        if (pageCurrent != pageCount)
        {
            @Html.ActionLink(" ", "Index", "Post", new { sayfa = pageCurrent + 1 }, new { @class = "next" })
        }
    }
    <br class="clear" />
</div>
```

POSSIBLE VARIABLES that I can change in Controller:

```
int postPerPage = 10; (This is not so important)

(Must-Have Changeable):

Posts = (IOrderedQueryable<Post>)Posts.Skip(postPerPage * (sayfa - 1)).Take(postPerPage);

return View(Posts.ToList());
```

POSSIBLE VARIABLES that I can change in View:

```
@Url.Action("Index", "Post" .... (This is also must-have)
```

MY DESIRED USAGE:

```
IN CONTROLLER:
Posts = Posts.ToMyCustomPagerClass()

IN VIEW:
@Html.Pagination()
```

How can I do that?
For now I create below class but ViewBags is problematic. Error: The name 'ViewBag' does not exist in the current context

```
public static class ePager<T>
{
    public static IOrderedQueryable<T> ePagedList(IOrderedQueryable<T> sinif, int page, int itemPerPage = 10)
    {
        int totalPage = sinif.Count();

        int pageCount = totalPage / itemPerPage;
        if ((totalPage % itemPerPage) > 0)
        {
            pageCount++;
        }
        ViewBag.PageCurrent = page;
        ViewBag.PageCount = pageCount;
        sinif = (IOrderedQueryable<T>)sinif.Skip(itemPerPage * (page - 1)).Take(itemPerPage);
        return sinif;
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to make this code reusable. Each time I need 'copy-paste and edit.' I want to use this code like. in CONTROLLER Posts = Posts.ToMyCustomPagerClass() and in VIEW @Html.Pagination(). Something like that

Answer (score 0):

Create a base class that contains the information you need for paging, and have your view models inherit from them.  Passing the paging information around in `ViewBag` is not very DRY at all.

Comment: I don't use view model. My knowledge is not so good. Because of that, I want to make project as simple as possible

Comment: You are passing in your list of `Post` objects.  What you want to do is create something like a `PagedViewModel<T>` class, where T is your `Post`.  Have a property of `Items` that are a list of `T` (your `Post`).  In your controller, get the list of Posts, create a new instance of PagedViewModel, and set the Items to your Posts.  you can reuse this view model for other pages, and encapsulate the paging details.

Comment: I edit my first post and add my class. Everything is ok except ViewBag. I do now have idea how to send data from my class to view